# Website for machine design calculations

Tags: python

I wish to create a website to compute simple stress calculations for machine design. I have attached a sample below. What tools do I need to build something like what I have shown in the attached image. I want the user to perform the calculation, save for later use and print it in the form of a report. Please note the items in boxes are user input.

[image]

Comment: Python is not the language for this. What you're describing (or at least I think you're describing) is a front-end web application, for which you need to learn HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I would recommend doing the code academy tutorials on those to get an idea on how to make your website.

Comment: You can go [link](http://www.w3schools.com/) to learn HTML, JavaScript. If you want use Python, you can use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to make your website. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create a web app.  If your language of choice is python, you can use the [Django web framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/). Web frameworks like Django and Ruby on Rails help organize your files for websites.  You can create a web app using Django but all your python code will be running on the server.  Any calculations would need to be sent as a request to the server and returned to the client.  JavaScript runs on the client computer and would be better for your application.  You can also store cookie data in the client computer to access later. In addition you should know some html and CSS to display your app.  The html, CSS and JavaScript can all be implemented in the Django framework.